# Does GCM work when device time is incorrect?

Tags: android

I am working on an android app which receives notifications from server using GCM. Therefore, wanted to know if device will receive notifications even if its time is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GCM service does not depend on the current time of the current device.

Now, if you have some data in your notifications related to the current time and after receiving this notification you play with it's data, probably you should make sure that the current time on the device and the one sent with the notification are in the same timezone. Or also you can rely to UTC time.